# Delphi XE6. [dcc32 Fatal Error] F2438 UCS-4 text encoding not supported. Convert to UCS-2 or UTF-8

Tags: delphi, encoding, delphi-xe6

Im trying to compile/build my project but i receive this error below:

[dcc32 Fatal Error] F2438 UCS-4 text encoding not supported. Convert to UCS-2 or UTF-8

The IDE do not show me what file/line i need to convert. I even dont know if is this i need to do really.

As i see, i need to convert the file for utf-8 correct?

This project as originally made with delphi 2010, now im trying to convert for XE6.

How i resolve this error?

Im using Delphi XE6, win 7 64 bit ultimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a source file, right-click on the Code Editor, and select "File Format | UTF8". Do that for all of your source files.

Or, narrow down the specific offending file. Try using [SysInternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which file is being accessed at the time of the failure.

Comment: In Process Monitor apply the following filters. "Process Name" is "bds.exe" and "Operation" is "CloseFile". The last file in the capture should be your incorrectly encoded file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error(F2438) in a Delphi\XE5 project which had  many *.pas files.  Error showed up when I had rebuilt all files in the project after deleting DCU's. I was able to uncover the one "*.pas" file that somehow got saved as UTF-32LE format.  The tool I found to locate the problem file was "File Encoding checker" which located the problem file in my project folder.  URL for the tool is https://encodingchecker.codeplex.com/.  I then had to convert back the problem "pas" file to be saved as UTF8\ascii text and on compiling the F2438 error was cleared up.